# Using CNN as a optimiser for finding ideal features?

Tags: opencv, keras, feature-selection

I have a task i need to solve using computer vision, but I can't figure out what kind of feature would be ideal to extract. I could possibly train a CNN network, which could do the classification, is it then somehow possible to learn what kind of features it uses, and what is used to discriminate class A from class b?
And then do the same just using openCV or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Actually, that is exactly what a CNN does, they learn features that might be the best for your particular data and task, and then you can use a trained network as a feature extractor.

This is pretty common use of a CNN, and OpenCV has some limited support for neural networks in the [DNN module](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html).

Comment: @Lamda Its not a feature type, you use the features learned by the CNN, as in actual numerical values that form a feature vector. This is done by forwarding an image into the network and selecting a layer that outputs an appropriate feature vector.